# Problema con kivy language

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Ya me dirigí a stacloverflow en Inglés y ruso, pero nadie me respondió. Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo declarar la variable kv de un archivo para el código de Python independiente? por ejemplo:

```
KV = '''
Screen:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'button'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.4}
        on_press: app.func()
    MDTextField:
        id: text
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
'''
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    def func():
        print(text.text)
Test().run()
```

¿Cómo hago para que el text se imprima sin el error nameerror? En otras palabras, ¿cómo configuro el mensaje entre las variables KV del resto del código? Fue escrito a través de Google Translator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el código que adjuntas funcione, son necesarios varios requisitos previos:

- Tienes que tener instalada la biblioteca `kivy`
- Tienes que tener instalado el tema "material" (`kivymd`)
- Debes incluir al inicio de tu script las dos líneas siguientes:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
```

Aparte de esto, tu código tiene los siguientes errores:

- El método `func()` que defines debe tener un parámetro `self`. Si no lo tiene se producirá un error cuando ese método sea invocado al pulsar el botón.
- Dicho método intenta acceder a una variable llamada `text`, la cual no existe, lo que producirá otro error. En realidad la variable a la que pretendes acceder es parte de la "pantalla" creada por Kivy y para poder acceder a ella (o cualquiera de los *widgets* en esa pantalla) es necesario que guardes antes el valor retornado por `Builder` en el constructor, pues ese valor será la pantalla, que tiene un campo `ids` dentro del cual están los widgets.

El código corregido sería así:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
Screen:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'button'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.4}
        on_press: app.func()
    MDTextField:
        id: text
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
'''
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen =  Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen
    def func(self):
        print(self.screen.ids.text.text)
Test().run()
```

Demo de funcionamiento (detrás está la terminal desde la cual fue lanzado el script, y en la que se verá el resultado del `print()`):

[image: Demo]